# How to access this.props from within an object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using the `react-navigation` library's StackNavigator. I want to have a header that includes both an icon and animated text. However, part of the text needs to be determined from `this.props` and I'm running into an issue:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft: null,
    headerRight: (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Animation.Text animation='fadeInRight'
                                delay={2000}
                                duration={1500}
                                style={{
                                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica-Light',
                                    paddingRight: 5,
                                    paddingTop: 10
                                }}>Welcome {JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.state.params.username)}</Animation.Text>
                <Icon
                    name='ios-contact-outline'
                    type='ionicon'
                    size={30}
                    color={'#77767c'}
                    style={{paddingRight: 5}}
                />
            </View>
    )
}
```

`this.props` is undefined here, but I have no idea how to bind an object to `this` or if that's even possible. I also tried moving the call out to a function:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft: null,
    headerRight: (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Animation.Text animation='fadeInRight'
                                delay={2000}
                                duration={1500}
                                style={{
                                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica-Light',
                                    paddingRight: 5,
                                    paddingTop: 10
                                }}>Welcome {this.getUsername}</Animation.Text>
                <Icon
                    name='ios-contact-outline'
                    type='ionicon'
                    size={30}
                    color={'#77767c'}
                    style={{paddingRight: 5}}
                />
            </View>
    )
}

getUsername() {
    return(JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.state.params.username))
}
```

and binding `getUsername` to `this` in my constructor, but for some reason the function never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function for `navigationOptions`. Please have a look at the example [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/202609d9cf70ce7ffa2dd7b99161b76978fe9b32/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/StackWithTranslucentHeader.js#L187), Consider the following snippet

```
static navigationOptions = props => {
  const { navigation } = props;
  const { state, setParams } = navigation;
  const { params } = state;
  // param has the required value
  return {
    headerLeft: null,
    headerRight: (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          ...
        </View>
     )
  }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: this gets me the warning: "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Comment: I used to do this for `header` part in `navigationOptions` like, `navigationOptions: navigationOptions => ({
    header: props => <Comp {...navigationOptions} {...props} />
  })`, let me take a look.

Comment: Hi @lmotl3, I have updated answer, found an example in `react-navigation` example. Sorry for the previous one. Please try this.

Comment: glad that it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a component's props in a static method because they don't have the context of the component, as it has yet to be initialized.

I can't run your code right now but there's an issue [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/147) on react-navigation's repo that might help.

Basically, they suggest adding this snippet to your componentDidMount...

```
this.navigation.setParams({
    username: this.props.username
})
```

...and then passing a function in your headerRight section like this

```
static navigationOptions = {
    ...
    headerRight: ({ state }) => {
        return {
            // access username as "state.params.username"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't run your code right now but maybe this will help.